# catching wild card route for missing routes, doesn't work when having additional routes files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I implemented a simple custom errors solution.
this one: http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages

everyhing is working fine except the missing routes in the routes.rb file..

in order to get to my error_controller when there is a missing route i did the wildcard solution: `match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'`

but... now when i try to enter a sub section of my site which seats under:
/admin, i get to the error page. the wilcard gets triggered, even tough the route for admin section is defined in a different route file, under: config/routes/admin.rb

what can I do? 
thanks

edit:
using rails 3.0.20 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: What's in your routes.rb file?

Comment: just regular stuff.. nothing special in my routes.rb file. the problem is the wildcard at the end of the file seems to go off before the routing system looks for the route in the second route file of admin routes section

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 3.2+, there is a simpler solution for your routes. First in 'config/application.rb' set your app as the error handler

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Now when there is an your app will look to your routes to handle it. In 'config/routes.rb' you can add a route such as:

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"
```

A more verbose explanation can be found [here.](https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq)

Answer (score 0):

OK so until I will update to Rails 3.2+

I simply put `'*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'` into the last route file that is loaded.

that way its truly in the end of the routes and now all my routes work. and the error is still fired when needed.